# Core Location Warning Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3, core-location

My core location works but I receive a warning at this line of code. locationManager.delegate = self; The warning is Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'phoneLocationViewController *const __strong'.  How do I get rid of this warning?  Here is my code

.h

```
@interface phoneLocationViewController : UIViewController {

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation    
*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;



@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

.m

```
@synthesize locationManager, currentLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation  
*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
self.currentLocation = newLocation;

if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f) { [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
if(error.code == kCLErrorDenied) {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
} else if(error.code == kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
    // retry
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error retrieving location"
                                                    message:[error description]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self; (I GET THE WARNING HERE)
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
```

Comment: I wonder why was this question downvoted? +1 from me to balance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your class as implementing the protocol of the delegate of the location manager.

```
@interface phoneLocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to your interface declaration.

```
@interface phoneLocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    ....
}
```